# Reading DBF Files in R

Tags: r

Good day

All i want to do is declare a column as a character field in my data when I read it in from a large .dbf file I can read in characters from a csv but this throws an error when I read in dbf files.

Here's the code I want to read in .df files with

```
    CMBD<- read.dbf("C:\\Users\\boka7002\\Documents\\Simulations\\Raw\\nCMBDB.dbf")
```

Here is the equivalent in CSV files

```
    CMBD<- read.csv("C:\\Users\\boka7002\\Documents\\Simulations\\Raw\\nCMBDB.dbf", colClasses = c("P_CODE"="character"))
```

I currently cannot run colclasses when reading .dbf files so what is an alternative method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The documentation for `foreign::read.dbf` suggests that the field type is encoded in the DBF file itself, unlike CSV which is just plain text, which is why you wouldn't have/need any options to specify the field types. What type do you get for your column, instead of character? If it's factor, set `as.is = TRUE`.

Comment: Oh I see Chris, thank you so much for the help.